How can I print the output of an array filled with strings in a specific horizontal layout?
I was instructed to write a program that would take an array with 4 columns, up to 100 rows. The array would be filled with strings based on user input, and then there was a predefined string that would end the user input loop and print the output of the array in a specific format, with each column representing a specific field.
Example:
Item     Price     Quantity     Subtotal

Fish      2         3            $6

That was how the final output was supposed to look and we were specifically asked to use a for loop to make this happen. I had no trouble up until it came time to finally display the data, everything I tried resulted in the array printing out in either a vertical format with each data point of the array printing on a separate line or printing in one line with no spaces or breaks.
Console.WriteLine("         Your receipt");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Item name          Price        Quantity        Subtotal");

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join("    ", items[i , j]));
    }
}

This was the last iteration of code I used, I tried String.Join hoping that would result in the correct output but that did not work. For reference here, count is a variable that tracks how many total rows have been added by the user so that the array didn't print out a bunch of 0s.
Where did I go wrong here?

items[i , j] is a single item (word) in the array.  You can use Console.Write(items[i, j]); because Write does not add a newline. Then, add a newline after the inner loop with Console.WriteLine().

Then, have a look at this to keep them aligned: .NET Format a string with fixed spaces

Make one pass through the array to find the maximum string length for each column. Then once you know that, add two or three to each column width (for spacing) and follow @001's suggestion to find out how to formatbeach line (and the fields in each line)

@001 thank you for the feedback, I did try that and the result was that each data point in the array printed on it's own line rather than having each row printed on a single line.

That doesn't sound right. Here's an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b3sCLC

@001 That worked, I put the final WriteLine in the wrong section of the loop the first time around. Thank you for helping.
